# Acceptance of payment cards and Euro in Bucharest

Tags: money, payment-cards, romania, bucharest

I shall shortly be spending 24 hours in Bucharest and would prefer not to change money for such a short visit. We have Visa and Mastercard debit and credit cards. Our hotel is prepaid. Are cards widely accepted for small amounts like a coffee or for admission to tourist attractions and are they widely accepted for restaurants?

We will have a supply of Euros with us. Are they accepted for similar circumstances? I am aware that I will get a poor exchange rate buying a coffee with Euros but I can accept that.

Comment: Coffee shops and tourist attractions in a usual capital are usually 99% chance card-payable.

Comment: @bipll : Tourist attractions yes.  Coffee shops?  I wouldn't expect to be able to buy a coffee with a credit card in Berlin (you might get lucky, but you might not too).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been going to Bucharest often during the last ten years. The acceptance of credit cards is good, although varies. Generally:

- Taxis and public transport **do not** accept any cards. You can take Uber, which works there, or prearrange airport transit with hotel. A taxi ride should be around 30-50 RON (7-12 Euro) one way. There is still no decent public transport from OTP airport to the city center.
- Pretty much all restaurants and cafes in city center/Lipscani area accept them. But always inquiry with the staff, as sometimes (rarely) their credit card machine is broken.
- ATMs are everywhere though, so you have a backup option.
- Euros are not officially accepted, and I have never seen anyone paying with them in those places. Souvenir stands might be more open.

Answer (score 1):

George Y.'s answer is very good, but I can provide more information:

- Indeed taxis and public transportation rely on cash (and make sure you also have smaller banknotes because they always claim not to have small banknotes to give back to a larger banknote). Also, a very recent Government ordinance virtually outlawed Uber's and Bolt's (Taxify) activity because they need a special license just like taxi drivers need. When going from OTP, make sure to use their terminals to call a cab and never accept other offers
- you can virtually pay everywhere using a debit/credit card (Revolut included) except for very rare cases, even for smaller amounts, although sellers would appreciate cash in these cases
- except for very rare cases all cash transactions must be in the local currency (RON)
- tipping is almost never included on the bill (you pay by card, tip by cash)